# Everything using MongoDB must throw UnknownHostException

Tags: java, mongodb, bukkit

I'm working on a plugin for a Bukkit (Minecraft) Server. I want to be able to write stuff to my MongoDB database, but any methods that include creating a mongoClient must throw an `UnknownHostException`, as well as everything it's nested in. For example: The listener class listens for a player login, which will trigger the login utilities class, which will trigger the database class. And all of them need to throw the exception. The problem is that adding the exception to all of them creates this error (or maybe something else is causing it): [server log](http://pastebin.com/qsPTLUAS)

This is a portion of the database class if it helps:

```
public static boolean checkForPlayer(String playername) throws UnknownHostException{
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("username", playername);

        //create client
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("some_address", 27017);
        //create database
        DB db = mongo.getDB("test");
        //create collection
        DBCollection table = db.getCollection("test");
        //create cursor
        DBCursor cursor = table.find(query);

        if(!cursor.hasNext()){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I'm not very good at java so the problem might be something silly :/

Comment: the problem isn't with the UnknownHostException, it's because you do not have all the required .class files on your classpath.  The stack trace you posted clearly states "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.DBObject"

Comment: Also, you should post the stack trace in your question so that we don't have to navigate between pages.

Comment: What do you mean? I have it added to libraries in the java build path.

Comment: your build path is for compiling your .java source files into .class files.  but you don't have them on your server's classpath. what type of artifact are you deploying?  a .war?  a .jar?

Comment: I'm exporting this as a jar, which is used as a plugin by the server, which is another jar.

Comment: If it is a jar, then it will not contain all the classes on your build path unless you are using something like the Maven Assembly Plugin to build it.  You will need to add all the other jars that are on you build path to be on the server as well.  Your server should have a directory named "lib" somewhere that you can place the mongodb jar.

Comment: nope. Just a folder called "plugins" for jars.

Answer (score 0):

You  have to add the mongodb driver to the class path. http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/#getting-started-with-java-driver